# React Спуск props в потомки

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Подскажите, как передавать props в потомка после метода map ? Вот простой пример

```js
const booksDescription = [
  {
    id: 1,
    bookName: "Понедельник начинается в субботу",
    bookInSection: 1,
    authorNumber: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    bookName: "Гарри Поттер и Орден Феникса",
    bookInSection: 6,
    authorNumber: 3
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    bookName: "Сказание о трех свинах",
    bookInSection: 1,
    authorNumber: 4
  }
];

const booksAuthor = [
  {
    id: 1,
    authorName: "Борис",
    authorSurname: "Стругацкий"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    authorName: "Аркадий",
    authorSurname: "Стругацкий"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    authorName: "Джоан",
    authorSurname: "Роулинг"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    authorName: "Джон",
    authorSurname: "Толкиен"
  }
];

function WorkSpace(props) {
  let Books = booksDescription.map((el) => (
    <BookItem
      id={el.id}
      key={el.id}
      bookName={el.bookName}
      authorNumber={el.authorNumber}
    />
  ));

  return (
    <main className={"main"}>
      <div id="FullListBook" className="BooksAll ">
        {Books}
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}

class BookItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const book = this.props;
    const authorsOfBookNumber = book.authorNumber - 1;

    const authorOfBookName = booksAuthor[authorsOfBookNumber].authorName;
    const authorOfBookSurname = booksAuthor[authorsOfBookNumber].authorSurname;

    const authorsOfBookFull = authorOfBookSurname + " " + authorOfBookName;

    return (
      <div className="bl_book__item">
        <a className="bl_book__link" href="#">
          <BookImg/>
          <p className="bl_book__name">
            <p className="bl_book__title">{book.bookName}</p>
            <p className="bl_book__author">{authorsOfBookFull}</p>
          </p>
        </a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function BookImg(){
  
  return (
    <div class="book_picture">
      <span>Книга по счету №</span>
      <img src="image.png" alt="Author + Book name"/>
    </div>
  )
  
}

function App() {
  return <WorkSpace />;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.bl_book__item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  max-resolution: 40px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

article {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Вопрос - как в компонент BookImg передать значения bookInSection (для Книга по счету №) и значение alt которое по идеии должно состоять из текущего значения названия книги и её автора ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для alt просто отдаете в `<BookImg/>` параметры, а в `function BookImg(props)` их принимаете. Пример использования

```js
//~~~~~
const authorsOfBookFull = authorOfBookSurname + " " + authorOfBookName;
<BookImg bookDescription={authorsOfBookFull}/>
//~~~~~
function BookImg(props){
  const { bookDescription } = props;
  return (
    <div class="book_picture">
      <img src="image.png" alt={bookDescription}/>
    </div>
  )
  
}
```

Аналогично bookInSection передаете в

```js
<BookItem
  id={el.id}
  key={el.id}
  bookName={el.bookName}
  authorNumber={el.authorNumber}
  bookInSection={el.bookInSection}
/>
```

И следует сделать такой же проброс до `<BookImg/>`

```js
function BookImg(props){
  const { bookDescription, bookInSection } = props;
  return (
    <div class="book_picture">
      <span>`Книга по счету № ${bookInSection}`</span>
      <img src="image.png" alt={bookDescription}/>
    </div>
  )
  
}
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло, а вот у меня вопрос, ещё возник. А если необходимо провести проверку,. что если книга по счету >1. То надо прописывать строку с указанием номера книги, иначе - не надо. Как это реализовать ? Я пробую в BookImg создавть функцию проверки по типу                                                     function bookNumber(props) {
        if(seriesNumber > 1){
            return '<span className="ribbon volume">Книга № {seriesNumber}'
        }
  а потом подставить результат вызова в вывод BookImg но почему, то не отображает условие.